# How can I get 11ty to recognize an in-page link as the current page? homepage#about = page.url

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

I'm making my first 11ty blog. I am wanting to have 3 sections on my home page.

```
<section id="hero-section">...</section>
<section id="about">...</section>
<section id="contact">...</section>
```

I've made a navigation with links to `http://localhost:8080/#about` and `http://localhost:8080/#contact` which link fine, but I can't get those links to show the active state.

I've seen 11tys page object, but it doesn't work with these in-page links. I'm trying to achieve something like the following:
`<a {% if page.url == "/#about" %} class="underline"{% endif %}>About</a>`

Any suggestions? Thanks!